# Comparing two array values and deleting row if condition is fullfilled

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have an array with 2 columns. I want to compare the values of the first column, like this:

a[i+1]-a[i]<0.0025.

If this is true I need to delete the row with a[i+1].

This is my first attempt, but it doesnt work.

```
a = np.delete(a, np.diff(a[:,0])<0.0025, 0)
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: boolean array argument obj to delete must be one dimensional and match the axis length of 8628

8628 is the length of the array.

Another code i´ve tried is:

```
a = a[~(np.diff(a[:,0]))<0.0025]
```

But then I get this error:

TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. `np.diff(a[:, 0]) < 0.0025` creates an array of length 1 less than 8628, which means when you use it in `np.delete` that the dimension no longer matches with the original array.

I would go with your second attempt. Using `< 0.0025` results in a mask of items that you want to delete, which you need to invert using `~` to get a mask of results you would like to keep. You have to make sure to place your parentheses correctly: `~( np.diff(a[:, 0]) < 0.0025 )`. Instead, you can also use `>= 0.0025` to make a mask of items you would like to keep.

Lastly, you have to make sure to match the dimensions (given that `np.diff` results in one less element. You can do this by prepending `True` to signify that you always want to keep the first value. One way to do that is using `np.r_`.

Final code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(8628, 2) # Your array here

result = a[ np.r_[True, np.diff(a[:, 0]) >= 0.0025] ]
```

Detailed example:

```
Consider the array:   [ 1,   3,    2,     5,     3]
np.diff creates:         [   2,    -1,    3,    -2]
Using threshold creates: [True, False, True, False]
```

Note that when the next element in the original array is less than the previous,
the thresholding result in False too.

Finally, because there are now 4 values instead of 5, we prepend True.
This has the effect of always including the first element in the result:

```
Original: [   1,    3,     2,    5,     3]
Mask      [True, True, False, True, False]
           ^^^^  ~~~~  ~~~~~  ~~~~  ~~~~~
```

Then using boolean indexing, we get the elements where
the mask contains True to obtain the final result:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works almost perfectly, the only problem I have is that this method deletes the last value. It´s probably because the difference to the next value, which doesn´t exist, is smaller then 0.0025. Is there a solution for that problem?

Comment: See my edited answer for a more detailed example. Whether the final element is contained in the result depends on the final element itself and the element before it. Maybe the final element is just less than the one before it?